# Make a fixed header apears always in the front

Tags: html, css, header

I made a fixed header, but the problem is if an element has a position relative then it would be in front my header:
[image]
[image]

And also I can't remove them the position relative because it will ruin my style, so I wanna know how can I make it always appear in the front?

This is the html of my header:

```html
<header class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="Images/logo.jpg" height="50px"></a>
        <span class="menu-icon" id="menu-icon">Ver menú</span>
        <nav class="navigation">
            <ul class="show" id="menu">
                <li><h1>Huascaran group S.A.C.</h1></li>
                <li><a href="#¿Quienes somos?">¿Quiénes somos?</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Mision">Misión</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Vision">Visión</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Contactanos">Contáctanos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Enlaces">Enlaces</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

And the css

```css
.container {
    width: 85%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.logo {
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}

h1 {
    line-height: 1.3em;
}

header {
    background-color: aliceblue;
    padding: 5px 0px;

    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

header a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navigation ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    display: none;
}

.navigation ul.show {
    display: block;
}

.navigation ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.navigation ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.navigation ul li a:hover {
    background-color: aquamarine;
    color: white;
}

.menu-icon {
    display: none;
    padding: 20px 20px;
}
```

Comment: increase the z-index

Comment: I don't know why any tutorial I searched telled me that, thank you, but why didn't you posted this as the answer?